# Can you send texts from iMessage to someone who has Android and uses Handcent?

Tags: sms, handcent-sms

Can you send texts from iMessage to someone who has Android and uses [Handcent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms)?
And if yes does the iPhone user need to have Handcent?

Comment: I would think, no. iMessage is a different beastie than SMS. If iMessage can indeed send SMS, then it wouldn't matter if the recipient uses Handcent or not, as it's just a client for SMS. Any SMS client would be able to read and respond to the message.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering if the text will be received through Handcent: yes.  If you are wondering if you will get the group text styled messaging from iMessage while using Handcent: no, I don't think you will.

There are several other SMS options that do support group messaging though.  Android 4.2+ offers group messaging built into the native Messaging app, so if you are on 4.2+ then you probably just need to enable the settting in Messaging app.  If you are on something before 4.2 then you could use GoSMS.  That is what I used until I was updated to 4.2 and it does a great job.  It's not perfect, because Apple likes their iOS exclusivity with iMessage, but it will do the trick.

Again, I am assuming you're looking for a group text solution.  If you are not, disregard my advice.  If you are wondering if Handcent can receive an iMessage, it should, but you wont have a group text to reply to.